# Materialize css how to reduce space between input value and its border when it is focused

Tags: html, css, materialize

[image: Materializecss input field]

I m struggling to reduce the space between input value and its border.

Here is the codepen link [https://codepen.io/Chandrikadesai/pen/xJpXXj](http://codepen)

Comment: could you mark where u want to remove space

Comment: The hyperlink doesn't work, but the link that is displayed is in fact working

Comment: What browser are you using? I've checked it and seems to work ok on chrome

Answer (score 1):

The cause is indeed the `height` you've set to the input. The fix would be to lower the `height` and adding top `padding`:

```
input:not([type]), 
input[type=email]:not(.browser-default), 
input[type=email]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]) {
    padding-top:0.6em;
    height: 2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's being controlled by the height on the input itself, which you have a CSS value set for on your Codepen link. That controls the total height of the input block, but you can see that if you make that too small, or short, the label begins to cross over with the input text.

You can adjust that label text height by setting a `padding-top` on the `input` element. Doing so will give a cushion between the label text and input text, and then you can control the overall input height to move that border.